# The remote RPC to the application server failed for the call datastore_v3.Put()

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify, gcloud, managed-vm

I'm using Google App Engine, with Java, Managed VM and maven-gcloud-plugin.

When I run my app locally (mvn gcloud:run) I get random exceptions when I write to the Datastore (via Objectify) saying:

```
The remote RPC to the application server failed for the call datastore_v3.Put()
```

My code doesn't do much more than that

```
public class TestDAOImpl implements TestDAO {
    @Override
    public void save(Test test) {
        ofy().save().entity(test).now();

    }
}
```

On the actual App Engine instance, everything seems to run fine though...

Does anyone know why is that happening and how to prevent it?

Thanks

Comment: Hey.... you should add a bit more information in this. What seems to be triggering this error.... honestly, with just that error, there's not much to go on...

Comment: I wish I had more details, but this is really it... When I try to write using objectify, I randomly get that error...

That's what my code is doing, not much as you can see... 


`public class TestDAOImpl implements TestDAO {
    @Override
    public void save(Test test) {
        ofy().save().entity(test).now();
    }
}`

Comment: hmmmmm that sounds peculiar. Do you have any way to reproduce? maybe it's a non-ASCII character in one of the attributes of your entity, maybe it's when you push too much, too quickly... how often do you see this error?

Comment: It happens randomly and there's no actual load on the application, I'm just testing it manually.
This is the entity, but it happens also with other entities

`@Entity
public class Test {
    @Id
    Long id;

    String value;

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public Test setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public Test setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        return this;
    }
}`

Comment: My suspect is that the ObjectifyFilter in web.xml is somehow conflicting with Jersey 2 lifecycle (I use Jersey to create some endpoints)

Comment: Recently I moved my app to managed VM and I'm getting the same error. I still don't know why.... but I tend to think is related to managed VM, same code was working fine out of managed VM

Comment: I too recently moved to Managed VM and I am getting this error quite often. This product definitely does not seem ready for prime-time.

Comment: This is almost certainly a bug with the App Engine SDK.